# Please help me check the Parse Error code

Tags: css

I have a piece of CSS that validator.w3.org gives an error CSS: Parse Error. It is related to the {}. Please help me check it. Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL5nU.png)

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .table td, .table th {
    padding: 5px!important;
    .svg-5 {
    width: 1rem!important;
    height: 1rem!important;
    }
    span.text-title {
    font-size: 14px!important;
    }
}
}
body.yivic-main .yivic-post-single .entry-content > p:first-of-type:first-letter {
    float: unset;
    font-size: unset;
    line-height: unset;
    margin: unset;
}
body.yivic-main .yivic-post-single .entry-content {
    line-height: unset;
    text-align: unset;
    font-size: unset;
}
```

Comment: The part `.table td, .table th {` is missing its `}` - or perhaps you are trying to nest declarations, but that is not possible with plain standard CSS (only with LESS/SASS.)

Comment: Where do I need to add }?

Comment: Yes, you are writing scss in css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile in:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .table td, .table th {
    padding: 5px !important;
  }
  .table td .svg-5, .table th .svg-5 {
    width: 1rem !important;
    height: 1rem !important;
  }
  .table td span.text-title, .table th span.text-title {
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }
}
```

You can do it online on several sites like: https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/